# Calc 1 integral $\int{\frac{7}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Awhile ago one of my homework problems had the problem $\int{\frac{7}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx}$. My answer of $7\ln(2x-2x^3)+C$ was marked correct, but I don't remember how I got this answer after a recent go at it resulted in $7\arcsin x + C$

Online calculators haven't been able to verify if the two answers are equivalent. Does anyone have an idea how I got my answer if it is indeed correct, or is my answer just wrong and the homework system accidentally marked it correct?

Comment: I think the homework system incorrectly marked your answer correct; you could check your answers by taking the derivative

Comment: the first answer is incorrect and the second is correct. To convince yourself of this you can use the Desmos online graphing calculator (plug in 1 and x as the integration bounds and use a dummy variable t) and graph each function.)

Comment: @RyanShesler I think we have to plug in **$0$** and $x$ as the bounds to obtain the right integral

Comment: @sai-kartik I wasn't showing the OP how to get the exact definite integral, just how to graph the basic shape of the indefinite using Desmos which does not graph indefinite integrals. In the end, $0$ and $x$ vs $1$ and $x$ are equivalent in the context of the problem as the integral in the question is indefinite and thus one would add a $+C$ to the end of each definite integral.

Comment: @RyanShesler Yes..my bad..

Answer (score 1):

The integral : 
$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \mathrm{d}x$$
Is equal to :
$$\sin^{-1} x+ \mathrm{C}$$
So the answer for your question should be :
$$7\sin^{-1}x +\mathrm{C}$$

For verification you can check this [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pe8dkm8usf).

Answer (score 0):

Using $\arcsin x+C=\int 1/\sqrt{1-x^2}\operatorname dx$, your answer was incorrect, and the second one correct.

Answer (score 0):

Differentiating your first answer, we get

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[ 7 \log (2x - 2x^3) \right] = \frac{7}{2x-2x^3} \cdot \frac{d}{dx}\left[2x - 2x^3\right] = \frac{7}{2x-2x^3} (2-6x^2) = \frac{14(1-3x^2)}{2x(1-x^2)}.$$  This of course does not equal the original integrand.